# How to increase aws lambda Applied quota value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

As i observe on the services quota panel that the applied quota value of AWS lambda , is much lower then the aws default value. How can I increase this value?

I cannot find proper guidelines of how to increase the applied quota value as much of the resource related to it is about how to increase the default quota.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same process, use the `Request quota increase` function in the Service Quota's console. The [Lambda Quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) documentation gives some insight, that there are specific limits placed on new AWS Accounts, which get automatically raised over time.

The fact they don't explain this in the Service Quota's console isn't very user friendly.